# Sorting data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table of data in rail relating to a doctors patients. Heres a sample.[image: Data]

How could I organise the data by status. So there could be a seperate dropdown. The user picks a status, and patients with that status appear at at the top of the table.

Comment: For some reason it's not working in my cloud9 workspace for rails, but is for a small local html file

Comment: What isn't working?